# objectId gets changed in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to assign an objectId to mongoose schema having nested document. But somehow when it is saved, the ObjectId gets changed.

review.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var user = require('./user.js');

var reviewSchema = new Schema({
    item_id:String,
    review:[{
        item_review:String,
        user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'user'}
    }]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('review',reviewSchema);
```

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
    _id:String,
    login_type:Number,   // 0 :facebook, 1: google
    profile_img:String,
    ph_no:Number,
    email_id:{type:String,required:true}
},{ versionKey: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('user',user);
```

reviews.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var reviews = require('./../model/review.js');
var user = require('./../model/user.js');


var getReview = function(req,res) {
    reviews
.findOne({'item_id':req.body.item_id.trim()})
.populate('user')
.exec(function (err, review) {
   if (err) res.json({
            status:'400',
            message:'There is no data available'
        });
        res.send({
            status:'200',
            message:'Review List',
            data:review
        });
});
};


var addreview = function(req,res) {
    reviews.findOne({'item_id':req.body.item_id.trim()},function(err,revie){
        if (err) res.json({
                    status:'400',
                    message:'Oops, feedback can not be submitted'
                });
        if(revie){
            revie.review.push({
                item_review:req.body.item_review.trim(),
                user :  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)
                // user_id:req.body.user_id.trim(),
                // user_name:req.body.user_name.trim()
            });

            revie.save(function(err,review){
                res.json({
                    status:'200',
                    message:'Thanks for your feedback'
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            var newReview = new reviews();
            newReview.item_id = req.body.item_id.trim();
            newReview.review.push({
                item_review:req.body.item_review.trim(),
                user :  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)
            });

            newReview.save(function(err,review){
                res.json({
                    status:'200',
                    message:'Thanks for your feedback'
                });
            });
        }
    });
};


module.exports = {addreview,getReview};
```

How can I connect both models without changing actual id?

Comment: You seem to have pasted user.js twice instead of review.js

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I have updated my question

Comment: Also your first few sentences are vague, please be specific, which ObjectID gets changed. Give more details

Comment: when I assign **req.body.user_id**  to **user** , it does not remain the same,it changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using _id as string not as an ObjectId, I suggest you change the schema to this.

```
var user = new Schema({
    login_type:Number,   // 0 :facebook, 1: google
    profile_img:String,
    ph_no:Number,
    email_id:{type:String,required:true}
},{ versionKey: false });
```

remove _id as it is by default and needs to be ObjectId not string.